# Converting from a q object to a string

Tags: casting, tostring, kdb

I'm having some trouble converting an object returned by a q query to a string. I was using c.java
Does anyone have any sample code to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I can help but the question needs to be more specific. Normal table or keyed table?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing provided in c.java. You would need to write your recursive object printer or similar. Studio for KDB+ has some functionality like this.

Good starting poing will be https://github.com/CharlesSkelton/studio/blob/master/src/studio/kdb/K.java